# Beat frequency with tuning forks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency

If you have two tuning forks and you know that one tuning fork is 305 Hz, and when the tuning forks are pinged together you get a beat frequency of 6 Hz, then you know that the other tuning fork is either 311 Hz or 299 Hz. This idea I am fine with.

Now, the second part is as follows: if you replace the known tuning fork with one that emits a higher frequency, the beat frequency is 4 Hz. What is the frequency of the second tuning fork?

The answer is 311 Hz. But I don't understand how we can arrive there. The two things we know are $1.$ that the new frequency is $>$305 Hz and $2.$ that the beat frequency decreases from 6 Hz to 4 Hz. How does this then tie together that the other frequency is definitely 311 Hz?

The way it was explained was that there are two situations: if the other frequency was 306 Hz **(why? where did 306 Hz come from?)** then the beat frequency would increase and if the other frequency was 311 Hz **(again why?)** then the beat frequency would decrease. Since we know the beat frequency decreases from 6 Hz to 4 Hz, it must be the second case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you start with tuning fork A at 305 Hz and you know that B is either 299 Hz or 311 Hz.

Now you take C, which is tuned at >305 Hz, which means at least 306 Hz (in integer steps...). If B was 299 Hz, then, together with C, which is higher tuned than A, the Beat frequency would increase to at least 306 Hz - 299 Hz = 7 Hz. But the beat frequency decreases, therefore, B must be 311 Hz.